# Сглаживание текста SVG перед применением фильтра

Tags: javascript, html, svg, svg-animation

Фильтры SVG растрируют  исходное изображение, это означает, что отфильтрованный текст не будет сглаженным, что приведет к неровным краям.

Есть ли обходной путь для этого? Возможно ли использовать другой фильтр для имитации сглаживания, или, может быть, я могу каким-то образом сглаживать текст перед применением фильтра?

Relevant Filter:

```
<filter id="f">
  <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="0" result="blur" />
  <feColorMatrix
    in="blur"
    mode="matrix"
    values="1 0 0 0 0
    0 1 0 0 0
    1 0 1 0 0
    0 0 0 15 -8"
    result="goo"
  />
  <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop" />
</filter>
```

Вот как это выглядит в [песочнице](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-water-yny8u)

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Antialias SVG text before filter is applied?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66392327/7394871) от участника  [@aleclarson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2228559/aleclarson).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/66392327/7394871

Answer (score 1):

В этом [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/921297/28748) подробно разбиралась данная проблема

В качестве компромиссного решения можно попытаться:

1. Подобрать менее контрастные цвета для цвета букв и фона
2. К шрифту применить атрибут  `shape-rendering ="crispEdges"`
3. Выбрать шрифт, у которого при рендеринге  более резкие края

Например выбранный вами шрифт `font-family="cursive"` выглядит так:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="400" height="600" viewBox="0 0 400 400" >  
<text  x="35" y="150" font-size="100px" fill="black" font-family="cursive"> HELLO </text>
</svg>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`font-family = "Monotype Corsiva"` выглядит лучше.
Я думаю, что если расширить подбор шрифтов, то можно получить вариант совсем без зазубрин.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Применение фильтра SVG для сглаживания неровностей краев

Для фильтра `feGaussianBlur` выбраны параметры (последеяя строка матрицы) `0 0 0 29 -1`

Для фильтра `fecomposite` `operator="atop"`

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="400" height="200" viewBox="0 0 400 200" >  
<defs>
  <filter id="f">
  <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="1" result="blur" >
        
    </feGaussianBlur>   
            <feColorMatrix in="blur" type="matrix"
                values="
                  1 0 0 0 0
                  0 1 0 0 0
                  0 0 1 0 0
                  0 0 0 29 -1"
                  result="goo" />
            <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
        </filter>
</defs> 
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="silver" />
<text filter="url(#f)"  x="35" y="120" font-size="100px" fill="#444444" shape-rendering="crispEdges" font-family="Monotype Corsiva"  > HELLO </text>

</svg>
```

### Анимация атрибутов фильтра

```
<animate attributeName="stdDeviation" begin="0s" dur="8s"
  repeatCount="indefinite" values="1;6;12;12;6;1;1" />
```

***Вариант c оператором = "atop"***

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="400" height="200" viewBox="0 0 400 200" >  
<defs>
  <filter id="f">
  <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="1" result="blur" >
   <animate attributeName="stdDeviation" begin="0s" dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite" values="1;6;12;12;6;1;1" />
    </feGaussianBlur>       
            <feColorMatrix in="blur" type="matrix"
                values="
                  1 0 0 0 0
                  0 1 0 0 0
                  0 0 1 0 0
                  0 0 0 29 -1"
                  result="goo" />
            <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
        </filter>
</defs> 

<text filter="url(#f)"  x="35" y="120" font-size="100px" fill="#111111" shape-rendering="crispEdges" font-family="Monotype Corsiva"  > HELLO </text>

</svg>
```

***Вариант c оператором = "xor"***

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="400" height="200" viewBox="0 0 400 200" >  
<defs>
  <filter id="f">
  <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="1" result="blur" >
   <animate attributeName="stdDeviation" begin="0s" dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite" values="1;6;12;12;6;1;1" />
    </feGaussianBlur>       
            <feColorMatrix in="blur" type="matrix"
                values="
                  1 0 0 0 0
                  0 1 0 0 0
                  0 0 1 0 0
                  0 0 0 29 -1"
                  result="goo" />
            <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="xor"/>
        </filter>
</defs> 

<text filter="url(#f)"  x="35" y="120" font-size="100px" fill="dodgerblue" shape-rendering="crispEdges" font-family="Monotype Corsiva"  > HELLO </text>

</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66464138/7394871) от участника  [@Alexandr_TT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7394871/alexandr-tt).</sub>